# Composer having trouble with installing fresh laravel libraries

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php

I'm installing a new Laravel 5.6 ambient with composer, but every time i do a "Laravel new projectName", when i run composer install or composer update, it returns this error:

> Could not scan for classes inside
>   "path/to/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest" which does not appear
>   to be a file nor a folder

After hours of trying to fix it, I made a test, manually creating the hamcrest folder. When i ran composer install again, it pointed that composer couldn't read a file in the "psysh" library, when i went to check it, the folder was completely empty. I downloaded the files again and put them in the folder, just to test if it was going to run. After doing that and running composer install, this error popped out

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump  @php artisan
>   package:discover
>
> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>                                                                Class 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider' not found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump
>   event returned with error code 1

I don't know where i messed up, since this is a fresh install of composer + laravel. I ran composer diagnose, but everything is ok. Does anyone where is my error?

Comment: Delete `composer.lock` and the `vendor` directory. Then `composer install`

Comment: It doesn't work. I've created a bunch of new fresh laravel instances and the same problems appear.

Comment: Try reinstalling the Laravel installer globally.

Comment: I tried that. No luck. When i uninstall and reinstall, same errors occur

Comment: Hi @FernandoAlmeida, did you get a solution for it? I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: I got it but can't remember what it was :( hope you can find the solution too

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Tinker**

> composer require laravel/tinker

Once the package has been installed, you should add `Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class` to the providers array in your config/app.php configuration file.

then in console, make a

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I tried that solution, composer require laravel/tinker returns same error:

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                          
  Class 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider' not found

Comment: did you include this  `Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class` to the providers array in your config/app.php  ?
and try `composer dump-autoload --no-scripts`

Comment: I've tried to include the class in the array, but it didn't work. composer dump-autoload --no-scripts ran without problems