# Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1 when running composer install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm a bit of a newbie to PHP in general and the common solutions such as running composer update and other similar suggestions such as the ones featured in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409816/composer-having-trouble-with-installing-fresh-laravel-libraries) didn't work. Here is the complete error message when I try to run '''composer update'''

'''> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Finder.php line 640:

The "" directory does not exist.

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1'''

I suppose my not really knowing composer well does not help. I believe a path is missing to some folder or file in a config or .env file somewhere.

Here is the boilerplate's composer.json file I am starting with:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.3.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.29"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.21.0",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.6",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.21.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.5.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0.15",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [ "laravel/dusk"]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a flaw in Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump , have you reported the issue to the project itself? What did you do and in which directory beforehand? Also when asking about an issue with composer-php on SO , please see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md beforehand, there are some general steps you should follow. And for Q&A, with only the error message I'd suggest you continue to search for known cases, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004461 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/68662570 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/75273099 and so on ... .